# How to set height of HTML in JSPDF's fromHTML() and hiding overflowing content?

Tags: php, jspdf

```
doc.fromHTML(
  element.htmlString,
  .get(0),
  10,
  10, {
      'width': 50,
      'height': 500
    }
);
```

My problem is this height property seems to be useless since my HTML code overflows it and it shows the text. The height I do not know how to set and can't find any documentation anywhere.

In short, I just want my HTML content to be contained in specific height dimensions.